# Como selecionar informações de várias linhas DataGridView C#

Tags: c#

Estou mexendo com C# ultimamente e estou tendo dificuldades.
Quero pegar informações de várias linhas selecionadas no `DataGridView`, e, conforme o numero de linhas, passar essas informações para formulários que serão exibidos, contanto que, se duas linhas estiverem selecionadas, dois formulários serão criados (cada um com as informações de cada linha que foi selecionada), e assim por diante. O problema é que se eu seleciono uma linha, tudo certo, porém, quando eu seleciono mais linhas, ele sempre abre os formulários com as informações da ultima linha que foi selecionada.

Como fazer selecionar as informações certas de cada linha?

Segue o Código:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string email, nome;

      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvEmpresas.SelectedRows)
      {
          email = dgvEmpresas.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
          nome = dgvEmpresas.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
          trat = dgvEmpresas.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();


          frmEmail f = new frmEmail();
          f.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
          f.Show();

          f.txtEnviarPara.Text = email;
          f.lblTratamento.Text = trat;
          f.cboEmpresas1.Text = nome;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Aparentemente um erro no `foreach`:

Quando você percorre as linhas do datagrid, cada linha analisada está sendo colocada na variável `row`. Mas ao ler o valor, você está lendo de `dgvEmpresas.CurrentRow`.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string email, nome, trat;

      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvEmpresas.SelectedRows)
      {
          email = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
          nome = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
          trat = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();


          frmEmail f = new frmEmail();
          f.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
          f.Show();

          f.txtEnviarPara.Text = email;
          f.lblTratamento.Text = trat;
          f.cboEmpresas1.Text = nome;
      }
}
```

Como sugestão pessoal para o código ficar mais limpo e entendível, eu criaria um construtor no `frmEmail()` com o mínimo de dados que você precisa, e passaria os dados obtidos do datagrid via construtor. Ficaria assim:

Eu criaria um construtor como esse em frmEmail

```
public frmEmail(Form mdiParent, string emailDestino, string nomeEmpresa, string tratamento)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MdiParent = mdiParent;

    this.txtEnviarPara.Text = emailDestino;
    this.cboEmpresas1.Text = nomeEmpresa;
    this.lblTratamento.Text = tratamento;
}
```

E no seu evento de click ficaria assim:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var row in dgvEmpresas.SelectedRows)
    {
        var emailDestino = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        var nomeEmpresa = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        var tratamento = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        var formEmail = new frmEmail(this.MdiParent, emailDestino, nomeEmpresa, tratamento);
        formEmail.Show();
    }
}
```

É só uma sugestão. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito Obrigado, Max!

Comment: Opa, fico feliz. Marca como respondido ae. Abs e bons programas!!